# With select2, how to access the original select/input element after it's been processed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using a combination of `JQuery EasyUI` and `Select2` to be able to drag options from a right panel, onto a left select box.

In the original HTML, the select boxes are empty, and I only "add" anything to them if I drop an option on them,

```
<form id="section1">
<select class="select2" class="drop_target" id="selected_options" name="selected_options"></select>
<div>
<div class="draggable_option" data-id="1234">1234</div>
</div>
</form>
<form id="section2">
<select class="select2" class="drop_target"></select>
<div>
<div class="draggable_option" data-id="1235" id="selected_options" name="selected_options">1235</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Then in javascript, I do something like this,

```
$('.drop_target').droppable({
    accept: '.draggable_option',
    onDrop:function(e, source){
        var $dragged_source = $(source);
        var $drop_target = $(this);
    }
});
```

The problem comes at this point, if you're dynamically adding things to the select, you have to check it doesn't exist, and if it doesn't, you create a new option, and add it,

```
var new_option = {
    id: $drag_source.data('id'), data_id: $drag_source.data('id'),
    text: $drag_source.val(), selected: true};

// Set the value, creating a new option if necessary
if (!$drop_target.find("option[value='" + new_option.id + "']").length) {
    // Append it to the select
    $drop_target.append(new Option(
        new_option.text, new_option.id, true, true)).trigger('change');
}

var data = $drop_target.select2('data');
$drop_target.select2('data', data.concat([new_option]));
```

Clear as mud?  Unfortunately it goes wrong at this point.  While all calls to `.select2` from `$drop_target` work as expected, this is *not* the `select` that was originally in the HTML, this is a `div` that `select2` created, after hiding the original `select`, with an id attribute like `id="s2id_selected_options"`.  So when we append the new option to it, it *doesn't* get added to the select, and gets added to `select2`'s div incorrectly instead.

My HTML pseudocode is deliberately set up in this "obtuse" way, because my page is like that.  I have multiple forms, and multiple "identical" selects in those forms, generated by `WTForms`.  So the "general" method of selecting your select by id, `$('#selected_options')` doesn't work correctly.

What I need to do, within the javascript, is gain access directly to the *original*, now hidden, `select`, and I can't access it via id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have access to one of the elements that's "associated" with the generated by `select2`, you can access meta information for it via `.data('select2')`, or in this instance,

```
$(this).data('select2');
```

In here, there's loads of metadata that `select2` uses (which you can see if you browse the source).  For this question, to get the original select or input element, you can use,

```
var $drop_target = $(this).data('select2').opts.element;
```

Whether you're using a `select`, or an `input`, this gives you a `jQuery` element linking to it.  If you're using a select, and are only interested in that, you can use the shorter option,

```
var $drop_target = $(this).data('select2').select;
```

This *may* be in the docs somewhere, but I was unable to find it, and I'm also not able to find it by searching now, because searching the docs for "data" and "select2" returns a result for nearly every page of their docs (hence the reason I'm answering this question myself, to hopefully save others the trouble).